# Changing Red-Black tree to AVL tree algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree, red-black-tree

I need to write an algorithm receiving a red-black tree and transforming it to an AVL tree.
Doesn't have to be perfect code, pseudo-code is fine as well. Even main ideas to help get me started.
Don't know how to start, help please.
thanks !

Comment: For each node in the RB tree, remove it and insert it into an AVL tree.

Comment: That's not what I mean. The entire tree should change from being balanced by Red black properties to being balanced by AVL properties. I mean, by using rotations according to these properties, changing the existing Red-black tree to an AVL tree.

Comment: The AVL shape invariant is much stricter than the red-black one. I think the fastest way to convert from a red-black tree to an AVL tree is likely to turn the tree int a list, and then turn the list into a tree.

Answer (score 1):

You have a red-black tree:

```
data Color = Black | Red
data RB a = NodeRB !Color (RB a) a (RB a) | TipRB

instance Foldable RB where
  foldMap _ TipRB = mempty
  foldMap f (NodeRB _ l v r) =
    foldMap f l <> f v <> foldMap f r
```

This gives us `length` and `toList`

You want an AVL tree:

```
data AVL a = NodeAVL Int (AVL a) a (AVL a) | TipAVL

fromListAVL :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> (AVL a, [a])
fromListAVL _ 0 xs = (TipAVL, xs)
fromListAVL _ _ [] = (TipAVL, [])
fromListAVL _ 1 (x:_) = NodeAVL 1 TipAVL x TipAVL
fromListAVL d xs = case fromListAVL (d-1) (n `quot` 2) xs of
  (NodeAVL _ l v r,[]) -> NodeAVL d l v r
  (t,(x:xs)) = NodeAVL d n t x $
                fst (fromListAVL (d-1) (n-n `quot` 2-1)) xs

rbToAVL :: RB a -> AVL a
rbToAVL rb = fromListAVL depth lrb (toList rb)
   where lrb = length rb
         depth = calculateDepth lrb -- write this!
```